# Php magento SESSION variables getting unset before executing javascript code inside php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, session, magento-1.9

**I am trying to show pop-up using jQuery inside php code.**

setting value to session variable $SESSION['prod_id']="123"

When user is not logged in I am setting some value to session_variable i.e.  and as User get logged in I want to call javascript(inside php code) if value is set for this variable then show pop-up to user and unset the variable from session.

```
if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
    if (isset($_SESSION['prod_id'])) {
         Mage::helper('company/product')->addDatabase($_SESSION['prod_id']);
         $productName = $session->getData('product_session');
         if (!empty($productName)){
             echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
             jQuery(document).ready(function(){
              jQuery('.show-toast').removeAttr('style').css('display','block');
                }); 
            });
                    </script>"; 
         $session->unsetData('product_session');    
         unset($_SESSION['prod_id']); 
     }
  }
}
```

But the problem is that before executing javascript code session variable is getting unset.But if I comment out unset session line then it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As after huge struggle I noticed that Magento session was on server side,and it was resets before JavaScript code get called. We need something like callback function to reset session.
I have written One function inside JavaScript **unsetSessionVar()** that will call an api of server side and will reset session for **unset($_SESSION['prod_id']);** and working perfect

```
if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
if (isset($_SESSION['prod_id'])) {
     Mage::helper('company/product')->addDatabase($_SESSION['prod_id']);
     $productName = $session->getData('product_session');
     if (!empty($productName)){
         echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
          jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery('.show-toast').removeAttr('style').css('display','block');
            unsetSessionVar();
          });
        </script>";
     }
  } 
}

<script type="text/javascript">
  function unsetSessionVar(){
    jQuery.ajax({
         url: 'company.com/api/sessionaction/unsetses/',
    }).done(function() {});
  }
</script>
```